# FlexPMD and TextMate setup question: Creating rules

Tags: apache-flex, textmate

I wanted to get some assistance into how to set up new rulesets for Textmate, as I can't find the pmd.xml file that needs to be modified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a default pmd.xml file anywhere, so I just used the [Adobe Flex PMD Ruleset creator](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flexpmd/bin/flex-pmd-ruleset-creator.html) and then exported the default set of rules.

[edited to add]

My project was running using ANT and Hudson so I just put it in the root of that.

However, to properly test this out using TextMate I copied my project to match the following [documented conditions](http://github.com/simongregory/flexpmd.tmbundle):

"The bundle is currently experimental, as such it expects the following:

- Source files to be in a saved TextMate project.
- ActionScript and MXML source files to be in a directory named 'src'"

I then copied my pmd config file into the project root, opened it, and ran the FlexPMD 'Project' option.

This gave the illusion of using my file, so I renamed the file and deleted  all but one rule to prove it wasn't being used.

The TextMate FlexPMD bundle documentation mentions:

- To specify a custom ruleset specify it's path using the env var TM_FLEXPMD_RULESET.

So I rather than create a global variable which would affect all projects, I created a [project dependent variable](http://manual.macromates.com/en/environment_variables.html) by:

> The way to do this is currently a little secret but if you deselect everything in the project drawer, then click the info (circled I) button, a panel will appear where you can set variables.

So my variable was `TM_FLEXPMD_RULESET` with the value `pmd_rules.xml`

When I then ran the FlexPMD 'Project' option, only one rule was being run.

Comment: Exported it where? I am not sure how to actually get TextMate to point to that.
Cheers

Comment: I've edited the answer to include TextMate specific configuration. I assume you've already installed the TextMate bundle? 

If so, try the new and improved steps above, they worked perfectly for me.